# How do I specify a location of a combobox value if a specific option button is selected?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am trying to automate my timesheet for work and what I want is when I select Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday etc. the combobox (containing the number of hours worked) destination will change to a specific column.

The code I currently have is below:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Timesheet")

LastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 row

ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = JobNumber.Text
ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = JobDescription.Text

'clear the data
 Me.JobNumber.Value = ""
 Me.JobDescription.Value = ""
 Me.Monday.Value = ""
 Me.Tuesday.Value = ""
 Me.Wedensday.Value = ""
 Me.Thursday.Value = ""
 Me.Friday.Value = ""
 Me.Saturday.Value = ""
 Me.Sunday.Value = ""
 Me.NumberOfHours.Value = ""
 Me.JobNumber.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
Unload Me
TimesheetForm.Show
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

 JobNumber.RowSource = "JobNumberList"
 JobDescription.RowSource = "JobDescriptionList"

 With Me.NumberOfHours
.AddItem "1"
.AddItem "2"
.AddItem "3"
.AddItem "4"
.AddItem "5"
.AddItem "6"
.AddItem "7"
.AddItem "8"
.AddItem "9"
.AddItem "10"
.AddItem "11"
.AddItem "12"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Use the `.top` and `.left` properties of the control.  Are you talking about on the form or on the worksheet?